# Calculating row height for fixed number of rows and table height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` with 3 `UITableView`s arranged vertically on it.  I don't want any of the tables to scroll.  The height for two of the tables (`A` and `B`) is being calculated from their content - the third (`C`) will re-size to fit whatever space is left on the screen.  For `C`, I will know how many rows I need to display, and I want to calculate the correct `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to make all of the cells just fit.

Right now, I'm trying to

- take the height of the whole screen
- subtract off the total height for `A`
- subtract off the total height for `B`
- subtract off some fixed blank space
- subtract off the size of `C`'s header
- subtract off the size of `C`'s footer
- divide by the number of cells in `C`

From how I figure, this should get me the height I need for each individual cell in `C`.  **Is that correct?  Is there anything I am missing?**  Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *) heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView = self.tableC)
    {

        // self.lcA & self.lcB are NSLayoutContraints that I'm setting after I calculate how tall those tables need to be
        // buffer is some white space padding I add to keep the tables from touching - it will be hardcoded to some constant before this code runs

        CGFloat target = (self.view.bounds.size.height - self.lcA.constant - self.lcB.constant - [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] - [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:indexPath.section] - buffer) / [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

    }

}
```

However, when I run this, it crashes, saying `-[MyViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I'm not explicitly implementing `heightForHeaderInSection` on this particular view controller, but the controller is set as `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,...>` in the `MyViewController.h` file.  **Will I need to implement `heightForHeaderInSection` in order to use this code?  If so, is there a way I can implement it and just force it to return some default value (something like `return [super heightForHeader];`)?  If not, why am I getting this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing "- [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:indexPath.section]" and all that stuff, i think you can access the header height by this:

```
self.tableA.sectionHeaderHeight
```

for footer:

```
self.tableA.sectionFooterHeight
```

also you have:

```
self.tableA.tableHeaderView
self.tableA.tableFooterView
```

You can have a better look in all of this in apple documentation: [TableView Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943)

Answer (score 1):

headerViewForSection is the method of UITableView so you need to call it not in your controller but in tableView.
You can also implement it in your controller, to return default value you need to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension as return value. This constant will work starting from iOS 5

Comment: +1 for `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` - I never heard of that before.  It doesn't seem to be working though - I'm just doing `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` (that's the only line in my `heightForHeaderInSection:`).  I put in some `NSLog`s, and it's just returning `-1.00000`

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually tried this directly, but this may give you a direction to go. `UITableView` descends from `UIScrollView`. As such, you can use all the properties of a `UIScrollView`, such as `scrollEnabled` prevent scrolling and `contentSize`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `contentSize` to set the `NSLayoutConstraint`s I mentioned in the code I posted, and I've checked the box to disallow scrolling on my Storyboard, so that's taken care of too.  What I'm looking for is how to shrink the cells in table `C` so that they all fit in the space I have.  I don't think there's anything on `UIScrollView` that can help me with that though, unless I'm missing something.